# cann't download spark dependency in zeeplin behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, apache-zeppelin

I'm playing with zeppelin (hdp version 2.5.1).

my zeppelin server connect to internet via a proxy server.
one problem i'm encountering is I can't download packages for spark.

I've set proxy in env, maven config, sbt config (sbt is not installed by default, I install it manually). none of them works for me.

The package i'm actually try to load is json4s, it failed. I try to use a java package:com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1, still no lucky.

the error message is :

```
ERROR [2017-09-01 05:11:04,824] ({Thread-36}   InterpreterSettingManager.java[run]:579) - Error while downloading repos for interpreter group : spark, go to interpreter setting page click on edit and save it again to make this interpreter work properly. : Cannot fetch dependencies for com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1
org.sonatype.aether.RepositoryException: Cannot fetch dependencies for com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1
at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.getArtifactsWithDep(DependencyResolver.java:181)
at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.loadFromMvn(DependencyResolver.java:131)
at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:79)
at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:96)
at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:88)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterSettingManager$3.run(InterpreterSettingManager.java:570)
```

The default repository "central" and "local" in zeppelin page is not editable, so I can't set proxy for them.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Hi, Zeppelin doesn't support proxcy for maven dependency downloading. The one work around you can use is, put the required jar files into `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/interpreter/spark/dep` directly.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-169